# selenium test in headless mode with Xvfb

Tags: selenium

i need to run selenium tests in a headless mode using Xvfb, in the pom.xml i have:

```
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>

        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>xvfb</id>
                <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>xvfb</goal>
                </goals>
                <!-- 
                <configuration>
                    <display>:2</display>
                </configuration>
                    -->
            </execution>

            <execution>
                <id>selenium</id>
                <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>start-server</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <background>true</background>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
```

when i run mvn integration-test, it failed to load Xvfb, selenium tests were still ran in firefox, i checked the following:

```
(EE) AIGLX error: dlopen of /usr/X11/lib/dri/swrast_dri.so failed (dlopen(/usr/X11/lib/dri/swrast_dri.so, 5): image not found)
(EE) GLX: could not load software renderer
(EE) XKB: Couldn't open rules file /usr/X11/share/X11/xkb/rules/base
(EE) XKB: No components provided for device Virtual core keyboard
```

anyone know what that means? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding -extension GLX to your Xvfb command line may remove the first two errors.

Comment: Do you mean `+extension GLX`?

Answer (score 4):

I found that the mesa drivers were missing in my setup.

```
yum install mesa-dri-drivers
```

resolved the problem.

Answer (score 4):

In Debian / Ubuntu, the package is "libgl1-mesa-dri", as in:

```
apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dri
```